# C# Interface? categories methods with the same name

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how to do something like this. So the scenario is I have 2 "DoLogin" methods in a different platform (Mobile Version, Desktop Version)

I want to make the code more readable and look something like this

Ex.

if I wanted to login to a desktop version.

```
webDriver.Desktop.Dologin(accountModel)
```

If I wanted to login to a mobile version.

```
webDriver.Mobile.DoLogin(accountModel)
```

this is what I currently have.

```
public static class Desktop
{
    public static void DoLogin(this ChromeDriver webDriver, AccountModel account)
    {

    }
}

public static class Mobile
{
    public static void DoLogin(this ChromeDriver webDriver, AccountModel account)
    {

    }
}
```

EDIT

This is what I'm currently doing to organize it.

```
public static class Desktop
    {
        public static void DesktopDoLogin(this ChromeDriver webDriver, AccountModel account)
        {

        }
    }

    public static class Mobile
    {
        public static void MobileDoLogin(this ChromeDriver webDriver, AccountModel account)
        {

        }
    }
```

whenever I call a method let say desktop what I do is.

```
webDriver.DesktopDoLogin(account)
```

or

```
webDriver.MobileDoLogin(account)
```

I guess whats important is it works.

Comment: No such thing as a static interface... Make Desktop and Mobile normal classes, which can implement an interface.

Comment: Create an interface with method `DoLogin` and implement 2 versions of it. Not sure what exactly is your question.

Comment: Is the functionality of the two `DoLogin()` methods same/similar or very different?

Comment: @JeffC if your asking about the code its different but the output is the same.

Comment: But what is `DesktopDoLogin()` is that a void, or is that constructer, i dont understand.

Comment: @Azhy sorry my bad it should be code is different but the result or what they are doing is the same. Its not a constructor you can see it by just looking.

Comment: Then if its not a constructer where is its type if thats a void wheres void keyword did you forget to write?

Comment: @Azhy yeah i forgot to write. my bad

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like using extension methods. This is a preference. I would have most likely implemented it as follows. I have never used Selenium before, so I'm not sure what interface `WebDriver` is/implements but you can get the gist of the pattern.

```
public interface IPlatform
{
    void Login<T>(T model);
}

public class Desktop : IPlatform
{
    private readonly WebDriver _webDriver;
    public Desktop(WebDriver driver)
    {
        _webDriver = driver;
    }
    public void Login<T>(T model)
    {
        // do login here
    }
}
// usage
IPlatform desktop = new Desktop(/*chromedriver*/); // or inject
desktop.Login<AccountModel>(model);
```

Comment: You don't like using extension methods or you don't like them for what the OP is trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can get this:

```
void Main()
{
    var webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

    webDriver.Desktop.DoLogin(new AccountModel());
    webDriver.Mobile.DoLogin(new AccountModel());
}
```

By doing this:

```
public interface IDoLogin
{
    void DoLogin(AccountModel account);
}

public class Desktop : IDoLogin
{
    private ChromeDriver _webDriver;

    public Desktop(ChromeDriver webDriver)
    {
        _webDriver = webDriver;
    }

    public void DoLogin(AccountModel account) { }
}

public class Mobile : IDoLogin
{
    private ChromeDriver _webDriver;

    public Mobile(ChromeDriver webDriver)
    {
        _webDriver = webDriver;
    }

    public void DoLogin(AccountModel account) { }
}

public class ChromeDriver
{
    public Desktop Desktop;
    public Mobile Mobile;

    public ChromeDriver()
    {
        this.Desktop = new Desktop(this);
        this.Mobile = new Mobile(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using some static voids like that:-

```
Public class desktop {
    Public static void DoLogin(AccountModel val){
        //code for desktop
    }
}

Public class mobile {
    Public static void DoLogin(AccountModel val){
        //code for mobile
    }
}

Public class webDriver{
    Public static desktop Desktop;
    Public static mobile Mobile;
}

//usage
webDriver.mobile.DoLogin(...);
//or
mobile.DoLogin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Interface?

Create one common interface with DoLogin Method, and Implement that interface in Desktop and Mobile class.

Common Interface:

```
public interface ICommon
 {
   void Login<T>(T model);
 }
```

Implement this interface in your Desktop and Mobile Class.